# Laravel is throwing exception event when I have try, catch

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4. I have a method in a class that gets a new instance of a model class. The class's full name is computed at run time, so there is a chance the computed class name does not exists. In the case the class does not exists, I want to ignore any exception and I want to return `null` instead.

But, when an exception takes place, Laravel still throw the exception below even thought I believe it should not

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'App\Models\CreatedBy' not found

Note that the string `App\Models\CreatedBy` was computed at run-time.

Here is my code

```
private function getForeignModelInstance()
{
    try {
        if (!$this->foreignModel) {
            $model = $this->getFullForeignModel();

            if ($model) {
                $this->foreignModel = new $model();
            }
        }

        return $this->foreignModel;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can ignore any error thrown and settle by returning `null`?

Comment: Catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception`

Comment: `FatalThrowableError` extends `Exception` I believe so it should not make a difference. Even though I tried that but getting the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except for me it's inside a database migration so I really need to be able to reliably run some cleanup code. I don't think solutions of the "try to prevent the exception occurring" type are valid. I'd like to understand why the basic php try catch isn't working here, are we doing something wrong?

Comment: Catching throwable worked for me (on php7), but like @MikeA says it appears FatalThrowableError extends FatalThrowableException which extends ErrorException which supposedly extends Exception according to the php docs [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to prevent exception happen instead of hiding it. So before make a new class instance, check if its exists:

```
private function getForeignModelInstance()
{
    try {
        if (!$this->foreignModel) {
            $model = $this->getFullForeignModel();

            if ($model && class_exists($model)) {
                $this->foreignModel = new $model();
            }

            return null;
        }

        return $this->foreignModel;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `class_exists` will not work using the short, aliased class name.

Comment: This is a work around. Does this means that Laravel does not honor the try..catch logic that PHP has?